# Books for a beginner (Pseudoconvex Domains)

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, several-complex-variables

Can anyone recommend me a book on **Pseudoconvex Domains** with include definitions, as well as a few examples? I have some course notes on that subject, but it's really abstract and theoretical.

I want to understand why **Pseudoconvex Domains** were introduced and ...!

---

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at Steven Krantz's *Function theory of several complex variables*, particularly chapter 3 on Convexity.  His books are usually very readable, and he provides examples and background material to support what he's teaching and proving.